# read CSV (actually semicolon) as Dataframe in PyCharm

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm, tabulate

I have done this kind of things in JupyterNotebooks and Sypder IDE, however, when i try to read a print a csv file in Pycharm, it shows the data with the separator, not tabulated as I wish.

I have tried the following:

```py
import pandas as pd

print("~"*50)
see = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\HP\pythonProject\Modulo6\bank.csv ", sep=";")
print(see)
```

And what I get in terminal is this:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     age;"job";"marital";"education";"default";"balance";"housing";"loan";"contact";"day";"month";"duration";"campaign";"pdays";"previous";"poutcome";"y"
0     30;"unemployed";"married";"primary";"no";1787;...
1     33;"services";"married";"secondary";"no";4789;...
2     35;"management";"single";"tertiary";"no";1350;...
3     30;"management";"married";"tertiary";"no";1476...
4     59;"blue-collar";"married";"secondary";"no";0;...
...                                                 ...
4516  33;"services";"married";"secondary";"no";-333;...
4517  57;"self-employed";"married";"tertiary";"yes";...
4518  57;"technician";"married";"secondary";"no";295...
4519  28;"blue-collar";"married";"secondary";"no";11...
4520  44;"entrepreneur";"single";"tertiary";"no";113...

[4521 rows x 1 columns]
```

Sample of raw csv data, copied straight from Excel :

age;"job";"marital";"education";"default";"balance";"housing";"loan";"contact";"day";"month";"duration";"campaign";"pdays";"previous";"poutcome";"y"
30;"unemployed";"married";"primary";"no";1787;"no";"no";"cellular";19;"oct";79;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no"

Comment: Please share the code output in formatted text instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Try going into the csv, copying the separator (the semicolon) into your clipboard, and paste that into your python code. Maybe there is something goofy where it is a different character that looks like a semicolon? not sure what that would be

Comment: @msamsami alright just did it.

Comment: @scotscotmcc hello scot, just tried wha you told me, which happens sometimes, but in this case didn't work.

Comment: Check if your CSV lines are enclosed in quotes (which would lead to the entire line being read as 1 column)

Comment: Could the fact that age is not surrounded by " have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: Run pycharm in debug mode, stop at print(see), click on "view as dataframe" in the bottom window and enjoy.

Comment: what version of python / pandas?

Comment: @scotscotmcc python: 3.10.7.final.0
pandas : 1.4.4

Comment: @AbirbhavG. the rows in the csv are not enclosed in quotes, however, every name of column and value is inclosed in quotes since they are stings, all but age, which is int type and is not enclosed in quotes.

Comment: @itprorh66 It could be, should I try it?

Comment: @СергейКох I just did that, and window popped up with the data, but the semicolon still were present and the columns were not aligned with the values.

Comment: Btw, I have just realized that:

[4521 rows x 1 columns]

That is the problem, pandas is understanding the headers as a single column, but idk why.

Comment: Could you share a sample of your raw CSV data? That'd help in diagnosing what the issue might be

Comment: @AbirbhavG. I have just edited the post with a sample of the raw CSV data.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the issue on my end. Using the exact same data and code you've shared yields a proper DF with separate columns for me.

Comment: @AbirbhavG. I haven even tried it in rStudio and still the same problem. I have no idea why this is happening.